# Can you execute Fancybox during the page "onUnload" event?

Tags: javascript, fancybox

That pretty much sums it up! I'm trying to use a stylized "exit popup" instead of the standard Javascript prompt box. Any advice?

Comment: Hmm. I visit your site (maybe by mistake), and you force me to accept by way of FancyBox modal dialog that I want to exit your site? Sounds great!

Comment: I'm really looking at concepts here, and trying to understand functionality. I just wanted to see if anyone was able to do it. Nothing sneaky :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This prbably the best you can do:

```
function unload(){
$.fancybox('<div>alalalala<div>', {
    'titlePosition'     : 'inside',
    'transitionIn'      : 'none',
    'transitionOut'     : 'none'
});
}
$(document).ready(function() {
   window.onbeforeunload=function() {
   unload();
   };
});
```

I think you cannot prevent the page to unload butyou can ask before if user wishes to leave or stay and in the meantime open the fancybox.

K